# How can I switch between R sessions in emacs-ess?

Tags: r, emacs, ess, tramp

I have two sessions open in Emacs-ESS: one on my desktop and one on a server using tramp. How can I tell ESS which session to use?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well I use

```
M-x ess-switch-process
```

all the time to switch between my (local) R sessions inside Emacs.  Sections 3.2 has details.

*Edit* As a follow-up to aL3xa's comment, I also have these in a my dot.emacs:

```
(require 'uniquify)
(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'post-forward-angle-brackets)
; Slightly more debatable
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
```

which makes the process switch *much* nicer.  Kudos to CGWalters, another Emacs user from whom I copied this.

Comment: @Dirk thanks - that works now; I was trying to do this before starting a new process, but now I see that I need to do M-x ess-start-process and then M-x ess-switch-process

Comment: @David, `ess-switch-process` is bound to `C-c C-s`, also a related functionality is `C-c C-k` from iESS which allows for easy navigation between iESS buffers.

Comment: Another "solution" is to use `C-x b` and type `*R` followed by desired session ID. It's a native Emacs feature (it's not ESS-specific). You'll see previously used buffer name in minibufer as default, so if you switch between two R sessions, this can be quite handy.

Comment: Good point. Two-or-so years ago I learned about `uniquifi` which makes buffer switching so much better and easier -- see my amended answer.

Comment: @Dirk `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)` makes my emacs hang

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Works fine here on Ubuntu with standard packages and no local elisp packages or add-ons.

Comment: Remarkable that after 10 years, the answer remains the same (I think) for ESS and emacs. Amazing!

Comment: :) Why would Emacs or ESS change in such a short time span?  That said I had forgotten about the `uniquify` snippet which I no longer use.  Adding it back does not seem to hurt though.