# Emacs: can I change the name of a started process?

Tags: emacs, process, elisp

I can use `process-name` to get the name of the process, but can I change the name after starting it? I looked in the manual, and even in the [source](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/src/process.c) and haven't found anything that seems like it would do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's only one line in Emacs' `process.c` source file where `p->name` is set for a process `p`, and that is in the function `make_process`. All other functions just read that value, they never (re-)set it. So it seems the answer to your question is "no".

You could, of course, try to implement your own function that changes the name of a process. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Writing-Emacs-Primitives.html#Writing-Emacs-Primitives)
for more information.